# ActionScript 2.0 loop frames X times and stop

Tags: frame, actionscript-2, counter

on my last keyframe of the timeline on the actions i putted this code

```
var counter = 0;

counter++;
trace(counter);
if (counter < 2)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}else{
    stop();
}
```

but the timeline continues to loop....
i imagine is because the counter is local variable and its overwritten every time when the last frame is played.

So how to declare the counter variable global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a new layer and add and initialise the variable in the first layer

```
var counter = 0;
```

Then on the last key frame, the rest of the code, with the gotoAndPlay() pointing to the second frame

```
counter++;
trace(counter);
if (counter < 2)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}else{
    stop();
}
```

[image: how the timeline looks - code in the first and last keyframes]

Comment: the solution is to goAndPlay(2) THE SECOND frame. Thanks